# Cors blocks discord oauth2 login

Tags: oauth-2.0, cors, discord, passport.js, nestjs

I'm trying to do a signup with discord feature. The flow looks like this:

[Auth flow of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6eR9.png)

The next frontend doesn't exist yet, so I'm testing it with a basic html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="onClick()">Login with discord</button>
    <script>
      const onClick = async () => {
        const res = await fetch('https://api.league.pr1sm.gg/auth/discord', {
          method: 'GET',
          redirect: 'follow',
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://api.league.pr1sm.gg',
          },
        });
        console.log('onClick -> res->text', await res.text());
        console.log('onClick -> res', await res);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[The backend code is located here](https://github.com/prsm/pr1sm-league-bkn)

The html is deployed on `https://league.pr1sm.gg` and the backend on `https://api.league.pr1sm.gg`.

This is the error that I receive:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.league.pr1sm.gg/auth/discord' from origin 'https://league.pr1sm.gg' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

[Request:A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEIaB.png)

[Request:B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRgPw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Cross-origin resource sharing within your application for this to go through.  You may also need to tell discord which callback url's are allowed into your application.

To enable CORS, go the **main.ts** and add this...

```
app.enableCors();
```

For more information, check out the official documentation.

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/security#cors

Comment: i already did that. exactly as you wrote and this way

  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'https://league.pr1sm.gg',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    preflightContinue: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    credentials: true,
  });